# android studio device monitor error "Java has started but returned exit code = 13"

Tags: android-studio

When i start android device monitor in android studio "Java has started but returned exit code = 13" error with java path files is displayed.
I am using "android studio (beta)0.89"

Answer (score 5):

I fixed this problem on my Windows 7 computer by installing the 64 bit version of Java 8. I did not have to uninstall or downgrade Java.

Be careful when downloading the Java installation. According to [this FAQ](https://www.java.com/en/download/faq/java_win64bit.xml), you will probably end up with 32 bit if you use the default installation.

Manually select the 'Windows Offline (64-bit)' version [here](https://www.java.com/en/download/manual.jsp), rather than letting the Java website choose for you.

Answer (score 4):

This has happened to me just now after installing the latest Java version (v8) which for some reason only comes with 32-bit support while my PC is 64-bit.

I fixed the issue by uninstalling the version 8 of Java which automatically downgraded to Java 7 and it works fine.

Answer (score 3):

I have been able to fix this issue by uninstalling the 32-bit Java 8 version I had, and then installing the latest 64-bit Java 8 version instead. (I didn't have to downgrade)

Answer (score 1):

Follow the path provided in the error pop-up. Add the java path in the eclipse.ini file located in the monitor folder in android studio.

Add : -vm
    C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\java.exe(Path to your current java file)
Before: -vmargs

Comment: There is no such folder "monitor" nor a file named "monitor.ini" anywhere in my Android Studio installation.

Comment: There is no .ini file in your android studio?

Comment: There does not seem to be an monitor.ini file in android studio.

Comment: Sorry i meant eclipse.ini file

Answer (score 1):

I think you are trying to open the wrong version of the monitor.exe it might have been changed during an upgrade. Under sdk/tools/lib there should be both the 32 and 64 bit versions under the "monitor-x86 or _64" folder. try either one if it works good. If you want to download the 64bit java version you must use a 64 bit browser. example in IExplorer 11 + you can change it back to 32 bit and back to 64 bit when needed. I did try the java upgrade before and was still getting the java error.

Answer (score 1):

Install both 32 and 64 bit of Java 8. That fixed it for me.

Comment: Installing the 64 bit version of the latest Java (v8, I guess) fixed it for me. I figured this out by going to the path to the Android Monitor mentioned in the error (C:\Users\adam\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\tools\lib\monitor-x86\monitor.exe) and running it. The 32 bit version actually worked and the 64 bit version (C:\Users\adam\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\tools\lib\monitor-x86_64\monitor.exe) did not work (produced the error in question). So I figured it had something to do with 64 bit Java; seems that was the case.

Answer (score 0):

Found solution:

- Uninstall Java 8 Update (64-bit)
- Install [Java 7](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/java-archive-downloads-javase7-521261.html) Update 71 (64 bit)

I also downgraded JDK from 8 to 7, but it might be not required

Answer (score 0):

If you are running win8.X just go to control panel and uninstall the java 8 version and after everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue, even though I had the latest x64 build of the Java 8 JDK installed and set to the JAVA_HOME environment variable.

For me at least, the first line of the error popup shows that it is using Oracle's symlink at C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath to find the correct location of javaw.exe. In my case, this was actually pointing to the x86 build of the same version of the JRE, which I also had installed for some reason.

I ended up cleaning house and uninstalling all versions of JRE/JDK, and then reinstalling the latest x64 JDK. This realigned the symlinks, and now it's running smoothly.

Most of the other answers should help resolve this same problem, but for diagnostic purposes if you do have the x64 version installed already, it will probably help to check C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath.

Answer (score 0):

[SOLUTION]

Go to following file in your android SDK
Sdk\tools\lib\monitor-x86_64\monitor.ini

and add following line, you might have to change the path to your java
-vm C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\java.exe
just before  "-vmargs "

Comment: First, you repeat another solution. Is there any reason for that? Second, unfortunatelly your solution didn't work for me