# Problems starting "Android device Monitor"

Tags: android

I always get a Error message when launching "Android device Monitor".

There is no error when launching Android Studio, it's running without problems. The error is just thrown when launching Device Monitor.

I reinstalled JRE 64 bit (I tryed version 1.7 and 1.8) but the error is still there.

I use Windows 7 64 bit and Android Studio 1.1.0

My User Variable JAVA_HOME is H:#Install\Java\jdk1.7.0_75

[image: Error Message after launching Device Monitor]

What can I do? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Possible fix would be to increase the XX:MaxPermSize

http://www.javavids.com/video/how-to-increase-java-memory-fix.html

Also, seems to be similar to the following posts:

[-XX:MaxPermSize with or without -XX:PermSize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8356416/xxmaxpermsize-with-or-without-xxpermsize)

[to increase MaxPermSize memory in Java by command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16587727/to-increase-maxpermsize-memory-in-java-by-command-line)

Comment: I changed the XX:MaxPermSize to 1024 in the monitor.ini file but the error is still there.

Comment: you can check if you did this the right way: http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/configuration

Comment: I tried everything but without success. I also reinstalled Java like here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26311080/android-studio-device-monitor-error-java-has-started-but-returned-exit-code-1 but also without any success. What else can i do?

Answer (score 0):

I know quite some time has passed since this question was posted. Just replying for helping other people. It's not JRE that you have to re-install. But JDK. In fact the Android Device Monitor is not part of the JRE.
I had same issue and fixed by installing the appropriate JDK for my system (x64).